# Disable button when input is empty in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to check whether the input is empty.

- If not empty, enable the submit button.
- If empty, disable the submit
  button.

I tried `(oninput)` and `(onchange)`, but they do not run.

```
<input type="password" [(ngModel)]="myPassword" (oninput)="checkPasswordEmpty()"/>

checkPasswordEmpty() {
    console.log("checkPasswordEmpty runs");
    if (this.myPassword) {
        // enable the button
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In this case, I would leverage form validators. I would add the "required" validation on your input and use the global state of your form to disable / enable your button.

With the template-driven approach, there is no code to add in your component, only stuff in its template...

Here is sample below:

```
<form #formCtrl="ngForm">
  <input ngControl="passwordCtrl" required>
  <button [disabled]="!formCtrl.form.valid">Some button</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, you can create your controls in the component itself ;-) You're welcome!

Comment: Using new Forms API (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) - `<input name="passwordCtrl" required>`

Comment: I'm trying to use this for an `input` inside `mat-form-field`. But the button stays disabled even when I enter some values in the input field...

Answer (score 1):

To bind functions to events, you don't have to prefix them with `on`. Just place the event.

For example, if you want to handle the `keydown` ([plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/KImV8Fmp2nxGui5YMVW9?p=preview)):

```
<input type="password" [(ngModel)]="myPassword" (keydown)="checkPasswordEmpty($event)"/>
```

---

But in your specific case, since you already are using `ngModel` you are better off using `(ngModelChange)`:

```
<input type="password" [(ngModel)]="myPassword" (ngModelChange)="checkPasswordEmpty()"/>
```

Because it will pick up the changes when the user pastes (via <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd> or<kbd>mouse right click menu -> Paste</kbd>) the password instead of typing it.

See **[plunker demo for using `(ngModelChange)` here](http://plnkr.co/edit/magIInr47xySxFkMFKxk?p=preview)**.

Comment: Look for the `app/app.component.ts` file in the plunker.

Comment: @HongboMiao I just remembered something. In your case, using `(ngModelChange)` is probably better than `(keydown)`, because if the user pastes the password, the `keydown` won't pick up the change, whereas `(ngModelChange)` will.

Comment: Oh, I tried `(keydown)`, it also works when pastes the password. But I will switch to `(ngModelChange)` because this seems more "Angular way". thank you!

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer to record that. About pasting, try clicking with the right button and then clicking paste in the popup menu. This one `keydown` doesn't pick for sure. Anyway, glad it helped :)

Comment: Yeah, you are right, when right click to past, `(keydown)` won't work, because it is for keyboard only, ha

Answer (score 0):

When using the template-driven approach suggested by @Thierry Templier, the form object also has an `invalid` property.

So instead of:

```
<button [disabled]="!formCtrl.form.valid">Some button</button>
```

You can also use:

```
<button [disabled]="formCtrl.form.invalid">Some button</button>
```

It's a small difference, but overall cleaner syntax in my opinion.